# Audio recording application that uses ladspa plugins?

Tags: plugins

I'm looking for a good recording application other than Audacity that will work with the Autotalent ladspa plugin. It keeps crashing whenever I apply the Autotalent effect. Audacity is working fine with all the other plugins, just not Autotalent.
Or, is there a way to just keep Audacity from crashing when I apply the effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ardour uses LADSPA plugins. It is a digital audio workstation, check http://ardour.org/